# Console App Interface from another DLL Implementation Error

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

I have an interface in a DLL and am implementing it in a Console App for Testing

My Interface is as Follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Gemini.Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUser
    {
        IEnumerable<IUserDetails> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        string AdUserName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IUserDetails
    {
        int UserId { get; set; }
        string DisplayUserName { get; set; }
        string OfficeCode { get; set; }
        string UserEmail { get; set; }
        string AdLogin { get; set; }
        bool? LastActiveUser { get; set; }
        Gemini.Data.App_Consts.Access_Rights UserAccess { get; set; }
        bool IsPM { get; set; }
        bool IsSPM { get; set; }
        bool IsVdbUser { get; set; }
        DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        DateTime? LastLoginUse { get; set; }
        int? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and when I try to use it in the Testing App I get the following

> The type or namespace name 'IUser' does not exist in the namespace 'Gemini.Data.Interfaces' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

the Console App is as Follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Gemini.Data.Interfaces;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class User : Gemini.Data.Interfaces.IUser
    {
        private IEnumerable<IUserDetails> _UserProfiles = null;
        #region IUser Members

        public IEnumerable<IUserDetails> UserProfiles
        {
            get { return _UserProfiles; }
            set { _UserProfiles = value; }
        }

        public string AdUserName { get; set; }

        #endregion

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            User u = new User();
            Gemini.Data.Main.UserDetails ud = new Gemini.Data.Main.UserDetails(u, "Qpirate");
        }

    }

}
```

Visual Studio seems to reference the Interfaces and I can call Go To Definition on the Classes.

Anyone know of something else I can try?

I have already checked that the console app its targeting the same .NET Framework as the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually just deleted the old Solution and started again, but one thing i did notice was that when i created a console app the Target Framework was ".NET Framework Client Profile"

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me once, and i found out that the assembly name, and console app name were same in my case.

To troubleshoot, i would suggest first make sure that assembly name are different for dll, and console app.

If that does not solve, try specifying different namespaces  (both default namespace in project tab, and rename existing namespaces).

If that also does not solve, try to first merger the code of dll into app, and then move one by one. I hope codebase is small in your case.